# from innerHTML to dom methods when onclick exists

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this piece of javascript:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.innerHTML = "<span onclick='myFunc(this)'>click here</span>";
```

I would like to rewrite via dom methods (without innerHTML)
so something like this:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
var span = document.createElement("span"); 
...
d.appendChild(span);
```

What I don't know how to do is how to wire up the span object so that it calls the global function 'myFunc' passing itself (this) as an argument ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set its "onclick" attribute:

```
span.onclick = function() { myFunc(this); };
```

The "old-fashioned" event handlers bound via "onfoo" attributes are always invoked such that `this` refers to the element handling the event. Thus, you can just wrap a call to your handler function with a simple anonymous function to call your code and pass it `this`. If you don't actually need the element reference to be passed in as a parameter to your handler, you can just write:

```
span.onclick = myFunc;
```

In that case, your own function will have `this` available to refer to the affected element.

Comment: @chacko no, I don't mean that.  The `this` value will be correctly set up by the browser when the function is called.  You *could* write it your way, if you wanted to, but personally I'd prefer to decouple the function and not rely on the closure.

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = document.createElement('div'),
    s = document.createElement('span');
    s.onclick = myFunc;

d.appendChild(s);

function myFunc(this) {
    // do something with this
}
```

I omitted the `.createTextNode()`.

Comment: s.onclick = myfunc ??? what is it that make sure that myFunc is called with the 1st argument being the span ???

Comment: @chacko see my answer - that will work fine if you're OK with referring to the affected element with `this` instead of an explicit argument.

Comment: @chacko: if the function `myFunc` already exists, you can just pass the reference to `onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this using jQuery:

```
var span = $('<span/>').click(myFunc);
$('<div/>').append(span);
```

Alternatively, if you wish to use native DOM, look into `addEventHandler` and skip onclick - it will make your life better in the long run ;)